# Float multiplication gives -nan as result

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

I have the following piece of code:

```
float res = 0.0f;
asm volatile("fld %0\n"
             "fmulp\n"
             "fmulp\n"
             : "&t"(res)
             : "0"(1.2));
```

Then I print `res` with the following statement:

```
printf("%f ", res);
```

Instead of 1.728, the correct result, it prints `-nan`. However, with only one `fmulp` instruction, it gives 1.44. Does anyone have an idea what is  wrong with my inline assembly?

I just want to load a constant into a register and multiply it several times. For good reasons I have to use inline assembly and cannot use normal code.

Comment: `fmulp` does "pop" one argument from the FPU stack, so if you had two at the beginning, the second `fmul` will have only one available and some junk. I don't know the inline syntax, so I have no idea how you loaded at least one argument into the FPU stack (the second is loaded by `fld`), but generally why x87 instructions on x86-64, where SSE2 is baseline? You can also check MASM tutorial for x87 like http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/index.html to get better understanding how x87 coprocessor works (which was used before as FPU, later included into main chip, since 80486DX)

Comment: *"For good reasons I have to use inline assembly and cannot use normal code."* - there are no such reasons, which can be categorized as **good**, you are probably lacking some information, if you think there are some. (also the task itself *"load a constant into a register and multiply it several times"* is not something to be done in real code, in real code if you have a constant, you can pre-multiply it already at compile time, and use only one multiplication in calculation).  (BTW, so a quick fix is to change first `fmulp` to `fmul` and hope you have your constant in the second slot).

Comment: actually reading through it one more time, I don't get how the single `fmulp` works in gcc, what are the default arguments, is it `st(0), st(0)`, so the one argument in stack is enough? Maybe... it's hard to guess without debugger, and I'm too lazy to use gcc to compile binary. But then I'm not sure why even single `fmulp` works, would have to re-read the definitions and try in debugger, how the FPU stack looks after that...

Comment: @Ped7g the default is `st(1), st(0)`, that's OK the second time is OP changes that first `fmulp` into `fmul %%st`

Comment: What if you modify your code to `asm volatile("fld %0\n"
             "fmul %%st(1)\n"
             "fmulp\n"
             : "=&t"(res)
             : "0"(1.2));`

Comment: @MichaelPetch this works but as soon as I want to multiply 1.2 more than three times, I have the same problem. Actually I want to chain a number of multiplications...

Comment: @Ped7g thank you for the comment about the FPU stack. I thought floating point multiplications are done just like integer arithmetic, in registers. However, you know, there are situations where you have to not only produce working code but to do scientific experiments and you don't want your compiler to do anything else than what you say. This is what I would consider a good reason for using inline assembly.

Comment: IMO it's not, it's semi-good(\*) reason to use normal assembly. The inline part is quite tricky, and IMO needless in this case, if you can encapsulate larger calculation in the separate function. The call from C to asm will slow down the execution much less, than with some trivial single-instruction function. \*)Both C and C++ have quite well specified how calculation is done on native types, including gcc switches like "fast-math", etc.. affecting the resulting code and it's accuracy/behaviour/perf. If you are using `float`, your accuracy is already down to 32 bit IEEE-754 (i.e. quite rough).

Comment: I.e. for scientific purposes I would rather expect either at least `double`, or some arbitrary precision library. If you don't care about accuracy and you care rather about stability between builds on the same platform, then building the calculation parts as separate library, and not rebuilding it any more while working on other parts is probably a bit better, than introducing assembly into C source. (but pure assembly allows you to do 80 bit precision on the old x87 FPU, if you do whole calculation in assembly, that's rare(very specific) but valid reason for that). With `float` use SSE2 (?!?)

Comment: @今天春天 with the advantage of SSE2 instructions working with XMM registers, no more x87 FPU stack, so it may be simpler to write working assembly with that, if you didn't do stack-based programming before (even I, when I'm using x87 in 256B intros, I have to think about it for few minutes and re-check everything meticulously in debugger, if I got it right).  (the 80 bit precision mentioned above does apply only to intermediate results of course, the ABI can pass only `double` at most I think, i.e. you have to have inputs and outputs as 64 bit IEEE-754 for HW native FP types, or use SW types)

Comment: @Ped7g my program is neither supposed to be readable, nor does it require to deliver accurate results, nor do I care about beautiful code or performance. It is more about testing the behavior of floating point computations on my machine.

Comment: " The call from C to asm will slow down the execution much less" - well, asm is not called. It is a note to the compiler to "copy" the instructions into the binary...

Comment: Also, this code will never be run on another platform than mine...not even on another computer than mine.